# 'Invalid Argument' error with un-gzipping Blob in Apps script

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a script that receives a gzipped blob from 3rd party API. I'm trying to un-gzip it using `Utilities.ungzip()` but getting an Invalid Argument error. Here's a sample code:

```
var liveReportResponse = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url)
var unzipped = Utilities.ungzip(liveReportResponse.getBlob()) // Fails with Invalid Argument error
```

An odd thing is that I can extract the content using the Drive File as intermediate storage:

```
var image = liveReportResponse.getBlob()
var file = {
  title: 'some_file_.gzip'
};
file = Drive.Files.insert(file, image);
var file = DriveApp.getFileById(file.id)
var blob = file.getBlob()
var someBytes = Utilities.ungzip(blob) // It works
var data = someBytes.getDataAsString()
```

Would appreciate any help for fixing that.

Comment: Have you tried `Utilities.ungzip(liveReportResponse.getBlob().getBytes())`?

Comment: doesn't work either

Answer (score 11):

Eventually, managed to fix that with:

```
liveReportResponse.getBlob().setContentType('application/x-gzip')
```

`application/x-gzip` seems not to be documented anywhere, but I've got it from `blob.getContentType()`

Comment: Thanks for sharing that with us.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67687867/40961