# Unzip gz-files using GAS throws error Exception: Invalid argument

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to unzip DMARC-reports sent to my e-mail as attachments. It works fine with zip-files, but not with gz-files.

In my code I first get the correct emails by subjects. If the subject is correct this script is run:

```
var attachments = message.getAttachments();
  for(var k in attachments){
    var attachment = attachments[k];
    var attachmentBlob = attachment.copyBlob();
    var vedleggsnavn = attachment.getName();
    Logger.log(vedleggsnavn)
    var vedleggstype = attachment.getContentType();
    Logger.log(vedleggstype)
    if(vedleggstype=='application/gzip'){
      Logger.log("ja gzip");
      var files = Utilities.ungzip(attachmentBlob);
      }
    if(vedleggstype=='application/zip'){
      Logger.log("ja zip");
      var files = Utilities.unzip(attachmentBlob);
      }
```

If the type of attachment is a application/zip it is decompressed and saved in my Google Drive. If it's a application/gzip I get an error. This is my log:

- 10:43:21 AM  Info    yahoo.no!dotl.no!1621555200!1621641599.xml.gz
- 10:43:21 AM  Info    application/gzip
- 10:43:21 AM  Info    ja gzip
- 10:43:19 AM  Error    Exception: Invalid
  argument lagreVedlegg    @ Code.gs:42

I hope someone might help me figure out how to unzip gz-files, I didn't find any tutorials on using ungzip. (I found a place where they wrote gunzip, but it doesn't look like that is right.)

I found this: ['Invalid Argument' error with un-gzipping Blob in Apps script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60059821/invalid-argument-error-with-un-gzipping-blob-in-apps-script)
But I didn't understand it.

I was told my code is not sufficient. I thought since it works for zip, it was enough to only post the code where the problem happens, in order to keep it minimal. But now I'll post my complete function:

```
function lagreVedlegg(){
  var folderID= ''; //I deleted my ID
  var tittelen = "Report Domain: dotl.no";
  var tittelen2 = "Report domain: dotl.no";
  var tittelLengde = tittelen.length;

  var eldreEnn = new Date(2021,4,21); //huska at telling starter på 0, så måned 4 er mai

  var root = DriveApp.getRootFolder();
  var parentFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID);
  var antall = 20;

  var threads = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(0, antall);
  //Logger.log(threads)
  for(var i in threads){
    var thread = threads[i];
    var message = thread.getMessages()[0]; // Get first message
    //Logger.log(message)
    var tittel = message.getSubject();
    var tittelKort = tittel.substring(0,tittelLengde);
    Logger.log(tittelKort)
    var avsender = message.getFrom(); 
    //Logger.log(avsender)
    var dato = message.getDate(); 
    //Logger.log(dato)
    //Logger.log(eldreEnn)

    if((tittelKort==tittelen || tittelKort==tittelen2)  && dato > eldreEnn){
      Logger.log(avsender); // Log from address of the message
      var attachments = message.getAttachments();
      for(var k in attachments){
        var attachment = attachments[k];
        var attachmentBlob = attachment.copyBlob();
        var vedleggsnavn = attachment.getName();
        Logger.log(vedleggsnavn)
        var vedleggstype = attachment.getContentType();
        Logger.log(vedleggstype)
        if(vedleggstype=='application/gzip'){
          Logger.log("ja gzip");
          attachment.setContentType('application/x-gzip');
          var attachmentBlob = attachment.copyBlob();
          var files = Utilities.ungzip(attachmentBlob);
          }
        if(vedleggstype=='application/zip'){
          Logger.log("ja zip");
          var files = Utilities.unzip(attachmentBlob);
          }
        Logger.log(files)
        files.forEach(function(file) {
          Logger.log(file)
          //Logger.log(parentFolder)
          parentFolder.createFile(file);
        })
      }
      thread.moveToArchive();
      Logger.log(tittel + "flyttet")
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your script does not meet the requirements of [mcve]  message is undefined, there is no function declaration and as it is it is unusable.

Comment: Thanks @Cooper. I thought since it works for zip, it was enough to only post the code where the problem happens, in order to keep it minimal. I have posted the function now. 
Please let me know of any place where the difference between Utilities.ungzip and Utilities.unzip is explained.

Comment: It looks like MAYBE this is a solution, but beats me why, and I have to test it more on future reports.  After if(vedleggstype=='application/gzip') I add 
          attachment.setContentType('application/x-gzip');  
          var attachmentBlob = attachment.copyBlob();

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems to be a bug. `Utilities.unzip` only seems to work with files with MIME type `application/x-gzip` and do not support the modern `application/gzip`. There is [a bug report on their issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/189198795), already. Click the white star (☆) to give it more priority.

As a workaround you can set the content type to `application/x-gzip`:

```js
function ungzipAttahcment() {
  const message = GmailApp.getMessageById('...')
  const attachment = message.getAttachments()[0]
  attachment.setContentType('application/x-gzip')
  const blob = Utilities.ungzip(attachment)
}
```

Comment: Thank you, very helpful! I clicked the star, hope others might do the same :-)