# "could not decompress gzip" error with un-gzipping Blob in Apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, compression, gzip

In an apps script code, I have to download a gzipped compressed file and extract files out of it to store on Google Drive.
Following is the extract of the code that is relevant to my question:

```
  var resp = UrlFetchApp.fetch(file_download_url);
  var blob = resp.getBlob();
  blob = blob.setContentType("application/x-gzip");
  var blobList = Utilities.ungzip(blob);
  console.log("total g-zipped files: " + blobList.length);
```

Initially when I run the code without using setContentType( ), it complained as "invalid argument" error. Then, I found this useful post ['Invalid Argument' error with un-gzipping Blob in Apps script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60059821/invalid-argument-error-with-un-gzipping-blob-in-apps-script)
and used the proper content type for gzip files (not yet found anywhere on Google Reference pages).

But now it shows the error as:

> could not decompress gzip.

Please help.

Note: If I simply download that compressed file to my PC and use 7-zip program to extract files as .gz, it runs fine and extracts those files.

Further Addition as required for complete understanding:
Following are the first 30 bytes of file as extracted by hex editor - frhed:

[20,0a,50,4b,03,04,14,00,00,00,08,00,1a,44,e6,52,5b,79,b3,61,8c,4a,11,00,1b,39,12,00,13,00]

7-zip snapshot that works fine with .gz
[image: GZip file containing two image files]

7-zip snapshot that does not work with .zip, neither the Windows built-in decomporessor nor the `Utilities.unzip`

[image: 7zip fails on .zip]

Comment: Did you check to see if the data had already been decompressed?

Comment: @MarkAdler At least I am confirm that the data is not already decompressed because it is a set of 2 - 3 files bundled in the compressed archive. If I simply download that to the Drive and add a .gz extension and download it to PC and using a utility like 7-Zip, it decompresses it into a folder having those files.
But my requirement is to decompress that into the folder on G Drive automatically as these files are being posted / uploaded by the service provider.

Comment: How does it have multiple files in the gzip file? Is it a .tar.gz?

Comment: That is in fact a good question but it is not .tar.gz.
This website https://ogarniamsie.pl sends the link to download files via email to my client. Initially the script used to work fine to download and extract a couple of image files from the .zip file.
Now, the script failed extracting the zip files. I analyzed that when downloaded directly on PC, they don't seem to be standard zip files as the extraction from 7-Zip failed. But if I change their extension to .gz and then try to extract those, 7-Zip could easily extract those image files but `ungzip` from apps script still fails.

Comment: I have added 7-Zip snapshot which shows multiple files within .gz
I could not share the file's direct link being client's confidential data.

Comment: A gzip file can store only one file. It may in fact _not_ be a gzip file, despite the extension. 7zip may be automatically detecting what kind of file it _really_ is, and extracting the entries within. Can you provide the first 30 bytes of the file in hexadecimal?

Comment: First 30 bytes:
[ 'a',  '3c',  '21',  '44',  '4f',  '43',  '54',  '59',  '50',  '45',  '20',  '68',  '74',  '6d',  '6c',  '3e',  'a',  '3c',  '68',  '74',  '6d',  '6c',  '20',  '6c',  '61',  '6e',  '67',  '3d',  '22',  '65' ]. 
Regarding 7zip, if this same file is set as .zip, 7zip is unable to extract anything out of it.
Thanks for your time to analyze it.

Comment: That's not a compressed file at all. That is simply text: `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="`. Are you sure you're dumping the right thing? And please put this information needed to answer your question in the question, not in comments.

Comment: I though Blob.getBytes( ) will do that. But I have now used the frhed hex editor to extract first 30 bytes and updated the question with that data.

Answer (score 0):

As I suspected, this is *not* a gzip file, which is why ungzip cannot decompress it.

It is a zip file.

There are two extraneous bytes at the start (a space and a line-feed), but after that the `50 4b 03 04` is the signature of a local header of a zip file. From the remaining provided bytes I see that it requires PKZip 2.0 or later to decompress, that the first entry uses the deflate method for decompression, the modification date and time is 2021 July 6 08:32:52, the compressed size is 1,133,196 bytes, the uncompressed size is 1,194,267 bytes, and there are 19 bytes in the file name.

7-zip can, of course, decompress and extract zip files. zip files, unlike gzip files, can have multiple entries.

Comment: Thank you for the analysis. However, this is exactly where the problem started off and I somehow realized that it was gzip format. The script used to work fine like download the zip file and `Utilities.unzip` would extract but in the last few days, it could not unzip it. So, I started  analyzing it with 7zip which also complained about it being invalid zip file. And when I rename it to .gz, 7zip goes fine and extract those files. does it mean, it is the issue on the sender's app?

Comment: That description was mentioned in my earlier comments two days ago as well.  I am adding the snapshot in question that 7zip fails if this file is taken as .zip.

Comment: Remove the first two extraneous bytes. (The space and line feed.)

Comment: Thanks, this tweak works fine with zip/unzip if I use the hex editor software to remove first two bytes on PC. However, as the original problem is the apps script automatically downloading such files and extracting from zip, can you guide how to achieve that within apps script code?